# How do I change the link for mobile users?

Tags: html, mobile

I have a button that opens up a pop-up window for a contact form, but the pop-up is not scrolling on mobile, so I was just thinking that it might be easier to change the button for mobile only. Is there a way to plug in some code to make this work for now?

The code for the button is:

```
<a class="book-now call-popup" href="booking-form.html" title="">Book Now</a>
```

where if I take out "call-popup" it disables the popup and takes you to the url. Any way to set this up so that on mobile the "call-popup" is turned off/disabled?

EDIT:

Added the following

```
function checkWidth() {
if ($(window).width() < 758) {
    $('#popup').removeClass('call-popup');
} else {
    $('#popup').addClass('call-popup');
}
}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

and

```
<a id="popup" class="book-now" href="booking-form.html" title="">Book Now</a>
```

But it is not working. I mean, when I inspect the page, it IS working correctly, but it is still calling the popup even when the class has been removed for some reason. And strangely enough, it is working on my fiddle, but not my site:

http://jsfiddle.net/5SM9u/51/

EDIT 2: Since it was asked, here is the popup js

```
/*=================== Book Now Popup ===================*/
    $(".call-popup").on("click", function() {
        $(".booking-popup").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

    $(".booking-popup").on("click", function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        return false;
    })

    $(".popup-inner, .datepicker").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".booking-popup .close-btn").on("click", function() {
        $(".booking-popup").fadeOut();
    });




    /*=================== Popup ===================*/
    $(".call-popup-alert").on("click", function() {
        $(".popup").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

    $(".popup").on("click", function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        return false;
    })

    $(".simple-popup-inner").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".popup .close-btn").on("click", function() {
        $(".popup").fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: There's a ton of options from what I can tell. You could just put `overflow:scroll` on your popup, you could use javascript to remove the class, you could set part of a media query to either override that class on the smaller size or even toggle the visibility of a separate anchor based on size...and that's just a few off the top of my head, just depends on what route you want to choose.

Comment: So I added the following code (editing the OP) and it is still not working.

Comment: What's that call-popup tied to? Sorry I'm not familiar with it at first glance, is it from one of the UI frameworks?

Comment: I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: Oh jeez dude, is it literally just calling a css class like shown in your fiddle example? If that's the case we can fix this with a super quick media query.

Comment: Oh and I just checked, your JS works fine for me amigo. Here, I made it a little more apparent, but it works fine... [http://jsfiddle.net/c1jakx1f/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/c1jakx1f/1/)

Comment: I know, it is working on the fiddles, but I can't get it to work on my live site for some reason. I am re-going through all my code to see if there is something that I am missing...